# NAudio network streaming

Tags: .net, audio, streaming, mp3, naudio

I have an app that plays some mp3 files with NAudio and I spent a few days trying to send this sound over network to another pc, but I'm lost about what's the better way to do that.
What classes I need to use to access the buffer and how to re-build that byte array to be played in remote? What is best, send mp3Frames, or it could be better to send raw or pcm data?

I'm really lost, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend transmitting across the network as MP3, not PCM as the PCM files are a lot larger than the MP3.

The latest [NAudio source code](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) includes a demo (in the NAudioDemo project) of playing internet MP3 radio which will show you how to receive MP3 frames, decompress them, and put them into a BufferedWaveProvider for playback. I've written [an article](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-play-back-streaming-mp3-using.html) about how this works on my blog.

NAudioDemo also includes a demo of network peer to peer audio chat, sending the audio using UDP sockets, although MP3 isn't used for the compression.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's working now, but i still have a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's working now, but i still have a problem. I read mp3 frame by frame to play and send the rawData, but the buffer grows quickly (it's inside a loop) and i get buffer full exception. I've tried to change the buffer size but obviusly this is not the solution. I tried to read the next frame every time that bufferedWaveProvider reads a block, but in this case i haven't enough data in the buffer to play well the file. (too slow). Can you help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Quick and easy solution - just do a Thread.Sleep when your bufferedWaveProvider has too much in it, and wait until it has gone down. Better solution, put the MP3Frames into a queue. Another thread then monitors the bufferedWaveProvider and when it is getting low pops an MP3 frame off the queue, decompresses it and sticks it in the bufferedWaveProvider.

Comment: Finally I solve this controlling the bufferLength with a simple "If" before adding bytes... I think my last problem is panning the sound, because I don't use a WaveChannel, but I think I could fix it thanks to PanningSampleProvider. Thanks again!